# Best free advertising for Facebook strategy game

Tags: marketing, facebook

I have written a game for Facebook. I think the game is fun to play, although the graphic presentation is primitive since I am not a graphic artist/web designer

I am the only Facebook user playing the game at this time. It does not appear to appeal to FB's demographic audience who seem to prefer less complex and less challenging games. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could get the word out about my game to the proper audience while spending very little or no money?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/how-can-i-promote-my-game http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28879/promoting-a-browser-game (This isn't the place to promote your game).